# VBScript to detect if user exits/quits out of Internet Explorer window

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I have a progress indicator implemented as a small IE window which my script (VbScript) launches. Outside of embedding a script in the HTML file, I am hoping for a way to detect if the user exits this window, so that I can 'clean up'.

Is there any built in way, using VBScript (again, really hoping for not embedding script in the html), of detecting whether the user has exited this IE window? Currently, I am attempting to check for the non-existence of iexplore.exe, however this is proving to be a huge task due to the nature of this progress dialog, and it comes with too many risks to be acceptable.

Comment: Do you launch IE through the Windows Script Host Shell (`WScript.Shell`), via CreateObject or other?

Comment: I launch it through CreateObject

Comment: @Jaguar: because I have asked too many uninteresting questions on how to interface with this awkward piece of code I am stuck with. I will try to edit the question and make it seem more interesting than it really is. I admit this one is not a prize.

Comment: Make a for loop and check the TypeName of the IE object, like: if TypeName( ie ) <> "IWebBrowser2" then exit for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the CreateObject's second parameter, you can write your script to respond to IE events.  IE exposes the onQuit event that is fired when a window is closed.  Make sure you specify the WScript variant of the CreateObject method.  The native VBScript one does not support the required second parameter.

```
Set objIE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")

' Set up IE and navigate to page
   ' ...

' Keep the script busy so it doesn't end while waiting for the IE event
' It will start executing inside the subroutine below when the event fires
Do While True
    WScript.Sleep 1000
Loop

' Execute code when IE closes
Sub IE_onQuit
    'Do something here
End Sub
```

You can learn more about this method with a more thorough example [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176557.aspx).  This is a good asynchronous solution.

A second method uses WMI to launch IE so that you have a direct object to the running instance.  When the instance is closed, the object reference becomes null.

```
Const SW_NORMAL = 1
strCommandLine = "%PROGRAMFILES%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set objProcessStartup = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")
Set objStartupInformation = objProcessStartup.SpawnInstance_
objStartupInformation.ShowWindow = SW_NORMAL
objStartupInformation.Title = strUniqueTitle

Set objProcess = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
intReturn = objProcess.Create("cmd /k" & vbQuote & strCommandLine & vbQuote, null, objStartupInformation, intProcessID)

Set objEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent " & _
    "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' " & _
    "AND TargetInstance.PID = '" & intProcessID & "'")

' The script will wait here until the process terminates and then execute any code below.
Set objReceivedEvent = objEvents.NextEvent

' Code below executes after IE closes
```

This solution uses WMI to start a process instance and return its process ID. Then it uses WMI events to watch for the process to end. This in a synchronous method and script execution will stop and wait until the process completes. This could also be done asynchronously with the `ExecNotificationQueryAsync` method, but this type of scripting is much less common.

Comment: Great response Nilpo. Solution number 1 is cleanest so I'll start there. Unfortunately I can't get the OnQuit to trigger just with using the WScript.CreateObject(..,"IE_") and declaring the IE_onQuit(). I can only trigger if if there is some 'work' involved, such as a loop with a Wscript.Sleep inside. Even this seems timing related. I'll do my research and see what I can learn, but I might need your help. Edit: Ok I think I understand - WScript has to be 'doing' something. Need to figure out how this fits in with the rest of my script.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  Since the script executes asynchronously, you need to create an "endless loop" in order to keep your script from exiting before it receives the event from Internet Explorer.  Otherwise, the script exits when it reaches the last command that it can execute.  I've added a simple loop to my example.

Comment: I wish they had named this 'OnClose'. I was under the impression this event only fired if the USER took action to close it (via file | Close or clicking the X/close button). Still good stuff and I am still using this solution, however I won't be able to differentiate between the form closing because the script complete successfully, or if the user actively chose to quit.

Comment: True, but your logic (and response) should be the same either way.  You would still know on the backend if a form had been successfully submitted.  Without knowing exactly what you're doing I can't really suggest a specific way to handle this.

Comment: As a side note the OnQuit event fires on more situations than when the user closes IE. For example it can be fired when an Iframe parent is closed.

Comment: @Nilpo: I have tried your WMI approach and it does not set to null the objProcess object after closing the IE. Should it do it? It feels weird that someone outside your script can change the value of a variable ... Maybe we need to check some property of objProcess instead of its null value?

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia I've edited the answer with an improved code sample.